# replace the remote branch with the local one

Tags: git, gitlab

how can I replace a remote branch with the local one. if there is a file in the remote branch that does not exist in the local one then delete it.
Replace everything (files, commits). I was going to delete the remote branch, then create it again and applly a push, but I don't know if it's the right way to do it.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that you want the remote branch replaced with a local branch, and the effects of rewriting the history on other collaborators of that branch, you can force push to it from the local branch:

```
git push remotename localbranch:remotebranch -f
```

If the local and remote branch name are the same, then the command is even simpler:

```
git push remotename branch -f
```

So if your branch name is `develop` then the command will be:

```
git push origin develop -f
```

Comment: my branche name is develop then the cmd will be `git push origin/develop develop:origin/develop -f`

Comment: @Achraf it will be `git push origin develop -f `